# Confirmation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently made confirmation rule following rails guides like so:

```
  validates :email, email: true, uniqueness: true, confirmation: true
  validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
```

Everything works cool, but when i'm trying to update an existing record, i'm receiving an error:

```
irb(main):004:0> User.first.update_attributes!(name: "Some Nameee")
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "email@mail.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email confirmation can't be blank
    from (irb):4
```

And it's pretty obvious, because i have `presence: true` on `:email_confirmation` field. If i'll remove it, you can skip that fild and just don't pass it.

So, what should i do? Just remove `:presence` validation?

Comment: That's the joy of how Rails does validation by default. You need to use `on:` or create context-aware validation methods. `:on` allows creating validation contexts: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not a conditional validation that checks if email has changed? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

```
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, if: :email_changed?
```

Here's the doc on checking if the model instance has changed: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Answer (score 0):

I've solve it by explicitly defining `:on => :create` on validation rule

```
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :create
```

Is it ok to use it like that? I'm asking, because http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ is not mentioning that, so potentially it can be a bad decision.

Comment: So you don't want email_confirmation on updation?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy Maybe this person doesn't, but extending to specific contexts is trivial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

Comment: If you would use devise, there is a method for such case, when you want to update users without sending email: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FConfirmable%3Askip_reconfirmation!